# DNSMASQ block top level domain extension

Tags: dns, subdomain, wildcard, dnsmasq

How to block or match all domains with .com in dnsmasq?
I'm trying to actually block domains that end with **.bid** since they are ad related.

```
address=/.bid/0.0.0.0
```

Will this work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use `address=` in your dnsmasq configuration in order to accomplish this, for example:

`address=/.bid/0.0.0.0`

An easy way to do this on most configurations is:

`echo 'address=/.bid/0.0.0.0' >> /etc/dnsmasq.d/top_level`

Once this is added, you will need to restart dnsmasq:

```
service dnsmasq restart
```

You can use Dig to check the results:

```
dig site.bid
```

You might need to install dig separately. On apt-based systems such as Ubuntu and Debian, you can install it with:

```
apt-get install dnsutils
```

On Gentoo, it is in the `bind-tools` ebuild:

```
emerge --ask bind-tools
```

For Arch, it is in `bind`:

```
pacman -Syu bind
```

If you cannot install dig on your router, you can use it on a computer on the network, though be sure to flush your DNS resolver cache first to ensure the integrity of the results.

Comment: already tried...
unfortunately i dont have apt or full access. This is WRT running on ARM

Comment: dnsmasq errors out on startup if simply ".something" is entered.
Def need to recompile new version

Comment: Hopefully my edits to this answer are approved, I would like to note something I am not confident enough to add to the answer is that in my testing, the dig only shows the transformed dns request on client computers on the network, and not the router itself. This does make sense, and if your router is a device that does not offer access to the dig tool for one reason or another, you probably want to check your network clients anyway.